# microsoft dynamics crm opening quick create forms from lookup fileds

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

I need to know how to set which form to open when we click on the +New button in lookup fields in an entity form in microsoft dynamics crm.And is it possible that we can populate quick create form fields based on a form field ,on which the lookup field from which the quick create form was opened, is present?

Comment: You can't select a form using that button. You either get Quick Create if it is enabled for the entity and a QC form exists, or you get full form. If you have multiple Quick Create, only the first in the form order can be used (you can't even call a specific QC form using JScript from a custom button).

Comment: But i have two fields on my form which are having the button.But each one opens the same quick create form..It should open two different forms depending on from where it is opened.How to configure that?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to configure which Quick Create form to use depending on the field you start from our which button you press or any other client-side code. Only one Quick Create form can be used per entity. 
It might be a good suggestion for http://connect.microsoft.com (if it is not already there).

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution for opening quick create form.
We can set it by setting the following properties to the lookup field.
document.getElementById("lookupfieldname").setAttribute("entitylogicalname", "nameofentityyouwanttoset");
document.getElementById("lookupfieldname").setAttribute("entitytypecode", "codeforthatentity");

But I need to know that is it possible that we can populate quick create form fields based on a form field of the form on which the lookup field,from which the quick create form was opened, is present?